# Destructor for pointer and non pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

Why this can't work. Is there any way to do this?
I don't want to create a separate function for pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class temp
{
public:
  T val;

  temp(T value) : val(value) {}
  ~temp()
  {
    if(is_pointer<T>::value)
    {
      delete val;
    }
  }

};


int main()
{
  string * n = new string("cat");

  temp<string*>object(n);//ok

  temp<string>object2("dog"); //compliation error: type 'class std::cxx11::basic_string' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer. --- (but there is if statement!!!!)
  //i dont want delete in main

  return 0;
}
```

To compile i use g++ 6.3.0
Could someone help? Maybe, I need to separate declaration from definition?

Comment: Please provide more information like configuration, compiler, C++ version, and error details and actual question.

Comment: Technically your `temp` class doesn't take ownership of the pointer or the data it points to. So it should not attempt to `delete` it.

Comment: The eternal basic rule is: `delete` what you created with `new`, and `delete[]` what you created with `new[]`. If you pass a pointer into `temp` you still cannot be sure that it can be `delete`d without causing Undefined Behavior. Imagine that I use your `temp<int*>` for `int i; temp<int*> tI(&i);`...

Comment: `new string("cat")` is a code smell, not deleting it in `main` just makes it a little worse. Can you explain what the goal is? Why not `temp<string>`? or if you insist on dynamic allocation `temp< std::unique_ptr<std::string>>` ?

Comment: fwiw, "Is there any way to do this?" ... it isnt easy to understand what "this" is when it is only described by broken code, because we don't know what the "not-broken this" really is. Can you explain what `temp` is good for? Why do you need it?

Comment: With C++17 `if constexpr (is_pointer<T>::value)` would allow this to compile (though it will still have the issues mentioned by other commenters)

Comment: In modern C++, you almost never should use keywords `new` or `delete` except where an existing interface requires you to.

Comment: Don't do that. It's a bad idea. What if T is an array of pointers? What if it is a pair of pointers? What if it's a `FILE *` that needs to be closed? What if it is a pointer that cannot be `delete`d? Some of these things are impossible to check. Even speaking of things that are possible to check, you cannot check all of them because there are infinitely many. Whatever class/function/module creates an object that needs to be destroyed by means other than its own destructor, is responsible for its destruction.  Your class doesn't, and isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you have is that the branch of an `if` must always be syntactically valid, even if it is never taken.

You *could* do it with `if constexpr`, which is a "compile time if"

```
~temp()
  {
    if constexpr(is_pointer<T>::value)
    {
      delete val;
    }
  }
```

However this isn't safe.

How do you know that the pointer passed to `temp<T*>` was created by `new` and not `new[]`, `malloc`, or by taking the address of an object that wasn't dynamically allocated?

Rather than assume that pointers should be deleted, you should avoid having to know which pointers to delete

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class temp
{
public:
  T val;

  temp(T value) : val(value) {}

  // n.b. no need to define destructor
};

int main()
{
  std::string str("cat");
  temp<std::string*> object(&str);//ok

  temp<std::string> object2("dog"); // also ok

  std::unique_ptr<std::string> str2 = std::make_unique<std::string>("mouse");
  temp<std::string *> object3(str2.get()); // ok so long as str2 outlives object3

  std::shared_ptr<std::string> str3 = std::make_shared<std::string>("rabbit");
  temp<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> object4(str3); // also ok

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are suggesting to not `delete` at all in the destructor? Not sure if I understand the answer, because with your fix of `constexpr` the line `temp<std::string*> object(&str);` isnt't "ok"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number indeed